# Draw VU meter using Core Graphics in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I'm trying to draw a somewhat similar image to this, using Core Graphics:

[image]

I was able to draw the main arc, but I am not able to understand, how to divide arc into parts/draw graduation on arc? My current code to draw the arc is:

```
[path addArcWithCenter:point radius:radius startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(specific_start_angle) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(specific_end_angle) clockwise:NO];
```

I tried using `strokeWithBlendMode` but I am facing problem with position of graduations or ticks.

Comment: Post the code you currently have

Comment: @originaluser2 currently I am  just drawing arc using`[path addArcWithCenter:point radius:radius startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(specific_start_angle) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(specific_end_angle) clockwise:NO];`

Comment: draw the image on photoshop, and use it. That's the simple solution. Else you need to draw the arc with bezier path and make use of its dashes property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### [Teja's solution will work fine for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35040977/2976878), but it does require that you calculate your own start and end points for the graduations.

I suggest you create a function that let's you draw the graduations at a given angle of the arc, that will calculate the start and end points of the graduations, given a length.

```
static inline void drawGraduation(CGPoint center, CGFloat radius, CGFloat angle, CGFloat length, CGFloat width, CGColorRef color) {

    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGFloat radius2 = radius+length; // The radius of the end points of the graduations
    CGPoint p1 = (CGPoint){cos(angle)*radius+center.x, sin(angle)*radius+center.y}; // the start point of the graduation
    CGPoint p2 = (CGPoint){cos(angle)*radius2+center.x, sin(angle)*radius2+center.y}; // the end point of the graduation

    CGContextMoveToPoint(c, p1.x, p1.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, p2.x, p2.y);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(c, color);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(c, width);

    CGContextStrokePath(c);
}
```

You can then call this in a for loop (or however you want to do it) when you draw your arc for the main scale of your VU meter. You can also easily customise the color, width and length of given graduations at given intervals (for example, this code gives a thicker & longer red line every 5 graduations).

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGRect r = self.bounds;

    CGFloat startAngle = -M_PI*0.2; // start angle of the main arc
    CGFloat endAngle = -M_PI*0.8; // end angle of the main arc

    NSUInteger numberOfGraduations = 16;
    CGPoint center = (CGPoint){r.size.width*0.5, r.size.height*0.5}; // center of arc
    CGFloat radius = (r.size.width*0.5)-20; // radius of arc

    CGFloat maxGraduationWidth = 1.5; // the maximum graduation width
    CGFloat maxGraduationWidthAngle = maxGraduationWidth/radius; // the maximum graduation width angle (used to prevent the graduations from being stroked outside of the main arc)

    // draw graduations
    CGFloat deltaArc = (endAngle-startAngle+maxGraduationWidthAngle)/(numberOfGraduations-1); // the change in angle of the arc
    CGFloat startArc = startAngle-(maxGraduationWidthAngle*0.5); // the starting angle of the arc

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfGraduations; i++) {
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
            drawGraduation(center, radius, startArc+(i*deltaArc), 14, 1.5, [UIColor redColor].CGColor); // red graduation every 5 graduations.
        } else {
            drawGraduation(center, radius, startArc+(i*deltaArc), 10, 1, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
        }

    }

    // draw main arc
    UIBezierPath* mainArc = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:NO];
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    mainArc.lineWidth = 2;
    [mainArc stroke];

}
```

---

#### Output

[image]

---

**Full project: https://github.com/hamishknight/VU-Meter-Arc**

Answer (score 3):

You can draw bezier path with dashes ,something like this:[image]:

```
   //// Bezier Drawing
UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(54.5, 62.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(121.5, 39.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(54.5, 62.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(87.5, 39.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(190.5, 62.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(155.5, 39.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(190.5, 62.5)];
[UIColor.blackColor setStroke];
bezierPath.lineWidth = 10;
CGFloat bezierPattern[] = {24, 2};
[bezierPath setLineDash: bezierPattern count: 2 phase: 0];
[bezierPath stroke];
```

Else You can draw multiple bezier path and draw it similar to what you want:

Something like this:

[image]

For the small line:

```
UIBezierPath* bezier2Path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[bezier2Path moveToPoint: CGPointMake(65, 45)];
[bezier2Path addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(75, 63)];
[UIColor.blackColor setStroke];
bezier2Path.lineWidth = 1.5;
[bezier2Path stroke];
```

Comment: As @originaluser2 said it would work fine,eventually I tried this but was not able to get start and end points. However your solution was also part true. :)
Thank You!