# How to draw line path on top of arc using Canvas paint in Android

Tags: java, android, canvas, paint, mpandroidchart

I am working in an android application where i need to draw a graph like this.

I have drawn the arc using paint and canvas but i didn't know how to draw the line path along with the text as mentioned in below picture!

Any heads up on this would be really helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Short answer: canvas.drawLine() and canvas.drawText(). Did you look at this methods?

Comment: Hi @MDikkii Yes we can draw line and text using those methods that you mentioned. But we need that line angle and position calculation also.

Comment: Need some solution like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35909748/how-to-mark-points-on-a-path-drawn-using-cashapelayer-swift

Answer (score 2):

In order to keep direction of the line truly, you have to use many trigonometric functions and calculus. However, for such cases you can use `canvas.rotate()` for tricky solution. For the solution, first you calculate angle of line according to a value. For example, assume your arc represents total value of 200. The left side is 0 and the right side is 200, then you get the value of 80. With these values, you can calculate the angle like that 180degree * (80f)/(200 - 0) it gives 72 degree. Then you can rotate the canvas for drawing `canvas.rotate(70f,centerX,centerY)`. CenterX and CenterY are values of the center point of the arc. After that, you can draw your line as you draw to line at the left-bottom corner of the canvas `canvas.drawLine(0,100,20,100,paint)`.

```
canvas.save()
canvas.rotate(70f,centerX,centerY)
canvas.drawLine(0,100,20,100,paint)
canvas.restore()
```

Comment: Need some solution like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35909748/how-to-mark-points-on-a-path-drawn-using-cashapelayer-swift

Comment: This is the easiest and most clever solution I've found on this topic and I love it. Why rotate your lines when you can rotate your canvas. Genius.